# How to add row in datagridview with pre-data in c# winform?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview with data from SQL. I added 2 datas under each column , so if i view it in the form it would be like this..

Code is autoincremented

```
Code   --    Date     --     Total_Score

1         1/3/2015            20

2         1/3/2015            30
```

Now i want to add a new row..if i click the button it should add a new row with the details '3'(code is autoincremented from my database) , 1/3/2015(date should be current datetime) and the total_score cell should be empty so i could input a data. However it just shows a newly added blank row and i can't input anything on it.. here is my current code..

```
    private void btnaddcomp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable ds = (DataTable)dgsetcompt.DataSource;
        int index = this.dgsetcompt.Rows.Count;
        DataRow dr = ds.NewRow();
        ds.Rows.InsertAt(dr, index + 1);

        dgsetcompt.DataSource = ds;
    }
```

Comment: See this, it may help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/b22t666e%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should simply add data to your row in this way

```
private void btnaddcomp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable ds = (DataTable)dgsetcompt.DataSource;

    // Create a new row...
    DataRow dr = ds.NewRow();

    // Set the two fields
    dr["code"] = this.dgsetcompt.Rows.Count + 1;
    dr["date"] = new DateTime(2015, 1, 3);

    // Add the newly created row to the Rows collection of the datatable
    ds.Rows.Add(dr);

    // Not needed
    //dgsetcompt.DataSource = ds;
}
```

Comment: That's strange. I have tested it in a scenario like yours and the new row appears as expected. Could you add the code where you initialize the table and add the first two rows and bind it to the DataGridView?

Comment: I have edited my question and added the code there  ... I've been stuck for an hour on this.

Comment: Sorry but I can't find any error in the code above. Try to look at the properties in your DataGridView that are changed from their default values.

Comment: WHOA Finally fixed it! You were right , the problem was with the properties of my DataGridView haha! Silly me xD

Comment: If you tell us what is the property that caused this behavior it will be useful for future readers of this QA